# How does google decide which pages of a website to display in the search results?

Tags: google-search

If I search for "twitter" on google I get the following result:

[image: Google search result for twitter]

How does google decide which pages to display below the search result? (Login, My Twitter, Twitter / Create an Account, ...) Are these the ones that are accessed the most? Is there any way I can influence the ones that are displayed if I own the site which has been searched for?

Also how does google decide whether or not there should be extra pages in the search results? Does the site have to have a certain number of visitors or something like this? (I have a few web pages and this effect doesn't occur on all of them)

I am sorry if this has been asked before but I didn't what I should search for since I have no idea how this effect is called.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is called **sitelink** (more information about it can be found here: [Link](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334))

In brief, Google keeps secret the algorithm which decide which pages should be displayed and which ones should be hidden. However, via the [Google webmaster page](https://www.google.com/webmasters) you have access to a remove feature. ie : specifically mark a URL as needless.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Google uses the PageRank Algorithm for displaying the pages. After entering your text to search, it applies the Inverted Index over it and let know all pages which contains your entered key words to page rank algorithm. And the page rank algo. decides which one to display first and all others.